# Getting form values from xsl when asp file is called via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, xslt, asp-classic

My project is to send email having first name and contact details which will come from a form and the page should not redirect after clicking submit button.(for which i used ajax).
But i am not able to get the form values when i call the classic asp file(which will send email) via ajax.
If i put asp file path in action tag then it works fine and i am able to get the name and contact details but the page redirects which i do not want.

Please help me get the form values in my asp.

You may understand better if you see my code.

P.S: I am not using jquery.

**Code which works fine(HTML and asp)**

***HTML***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="sendEmail.asp">
   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

***ASP***

```
<%

Dim fname
fname=Request.form("name")
If fname<>"" Then

Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject="Customer enquiry for store champion"
myMail.From="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.To="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.Bcc="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.Cc="abc@gmail.com"
myMail.TextBody="This is a message from customer" & fname &". Please get in   touch with the customer using email"


myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic   (clear-text) authentication 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="abc@gmail.com" 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="Thp@dminuser" 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
'Name or IP of remote SMTP server
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.gmail.com"
'Server port
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing
End If
%>
```

**Code that doesnot work(xsl,JS, and same asp which is on top)**

***XSL***(xsl is perfect no need to debug it i am posting it only for reference)

```
<xsl:element name="form">
                <xsl:attribute name="name">ccform</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="method">post</xsl:attribute>
                  <xsl:attribute name="onsubmit">return validateform(this);</xsl:attribute>



                  <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">name</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="placeholder">Name</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">name</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>

                  <xsl:element name="input">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">text</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">email</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="placeholder">Email or Phone</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">email</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:element>

                  <xsl:element name="button">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type">submit</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">submitbutton</xsl:attribute>
                    Submit
                  </xsl:element>

            </xsl:element>
```

**Javascript**

*Ajax in javascript* (ajax in javascript is perfect no need to debug it posting it for reference)

```
function load(u,method,cb,data) { 
    "use strict";
    var xhr, V, i;
    method = method || 'GET';
    data = data || '';

    function ensureReadiness() {
        if (xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return; 
        }
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            return; 
        }
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { 
            cb(xhr); 
        } 
    }

    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') { 
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else { 
        V = ["Microsoft.XmlHttp", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",     
             "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0", 
             "MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0"];
        i = V.length;

        while (i--) {
            try { 
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(V[i]);
                break; 
            } catch (ignore) {} 
        } 
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;
    xhr.open(method, u, true);
    if(data) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
     }
    xhr.send('data'); 
}
```

*Calling ajax in my validateform function* (Maybe something i need to do over here to get the form input and bind it somwhow)

```
function validateform(form){
 var name = form.name.value; //it gives the value of the typed input in form field.
 var cb = function (xhr) {};
 load("/store-locator/uk/asp/sendEmail.asp","POST", cb,name);
}
```

Comment: MSXML2.XmlHttp is a COM/Active X object, so using it client side is going to mean your script will only work in Internet Explorer.  The latest version is MSXML2.XmlHttp.6.0.  It's quite easy to do xsl transformations server side in classic asp

Comment: Use jQuery and $.Ajax to post, it's way easier.  And set the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded for asp to be able to see the form data.  Also you need to use $.param to convert your post data to form data.

Comment: Also CDO.Message doesn't work without specifying it's configuration unless your app pool is an administrator, which is bad if it is.  Take it from me, I just spent a week rebuilding two classic asp servers that got hacked because they were using administrative privileges.

Comment: I am not supposed to use JQuery in my project hence i wrote this ajax in plain javascript. Can you please give a solution to CDO.Message which you said it will bring up more task for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the form values to your `xhr.send()`.

You could use `FormData` to do it. There's some good information on how to use `FormData` here:

[Using FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).

It'll work in most modern browsers, IE10+, etc. If you need to support older browsers, there's more information here:

[Submitting forms and uploading files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)

EDIT: To build up your form data to send via AJAX, your form values need to be a string of name/value pairs separated by a `&` character, so something like this:

```
name=steve&email=steve@example.com
```

So in your updated updated question the javascript should be something more like this (note: untested):

```
function validateform(form){
     var name = 'name=' + form.name.value; //it gives the value of the typed input in form field.
     var cb = function (xhr) {};
     load("/store-locator/uk/asp/sendEmail.asp","POST", cb,name);
```

}

That should get you the name value, you just need to extend it to include your email value. You might find you need to encode the email address, so you could use the [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that.

Also I don't know if it's a typo or not, but you need to call the `xhr.send()` like this:

```
xhr.send(data);
```

At the moment you have:

```
xhr.send('data'); // single quotes need removing
```

EDIT2: And for completeness, as I mentioned using `FormData` (this would be my preference if you don't need to worry about older browsers). Here's how you use `FormData` in your example:

```
function validateform(form){
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    var cb = function (xhr) {};
    load("/store-locator/uk/asp/sendEmail.asp","POST", cb, formData);
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me why `xhr.send()` **is able to** parse the form values when i am sending the sendEmail.asp file in action tag of html.(i do get entered name and email in form.)
`xhr.send()` is not working when sendEmail.asp is passed via ajax. It works fine when passed from action tag of the form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. If you aren't calling your javascript and sending via AJAX, then you aren't using `xhr.send()` at all. It's the browser submitting the form and it is *POSTing* the form data. Or are you saying you are always calling the Javascript and the difference between it passing the form variables to your ASP and failing, is whether you populate the `action` attribute of the `form` tag or hard-code it in the Javascript?

Comment: I have changed my code for `xhr.send(data)` please look into it and suggest what shall i modify more?
I want to use javascript to send the form data and i do not want to use action tag of form.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I wanted my project to run in old browsers as well so i cannot use FormData.
I will create an object with key value pair and pass it in the ajax.
Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xhr.send('');` is obviously not going to work if you want to make a POST request with the form data of your HTML form so you rather need

```
function sendForm(form) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open('POST', 'sendmail.asp');
  req.onload = function() {
    // handle response here
  }
  req.send(new FormData(form));
}
```

Comment: xhr.send(''); is working absolutely perfect and i am able to get the email. I just want to get the name and email which is entered in the form. Using HTML and putting the sendemail.asp in action tag is working fine. I dont know how to get form data when i am calling the file via ajax

Comment: xhr.send(''); is able to give me name and email value which is entered on form and when the asp is called in action tag in form. However it doesnot work when when i call the asp from ajax